# convert byte array to structure in c

Tags: c, arrays, serialization, struct, deserialization

I am developing a client-server application in C.

I want to send structure from the client as a character array and then convert the character array back to the structure at server side.

I have the following structures

```
typedef struct mail{  
    char cc[30];   
    char bcc[30];  
    char body[30];  
}

typedef struct msg_s{   
    int msgId;  
    mail mail_l;    
}
```

I want to send msg1 to the client.

```
unsigned char data[100];   
struct msg_s msg1 ;  
msg1.msgId=20;  
// suppose the data in mail structure is already filled.    
data = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(msg1));  
memcpy(data, &msg1, sizeof(msg1));  
write(socketFd , data , sizeof(data));
```

when I get this data at the server side, how to convert it back to the structure?

I want to do the same in both C and java language.

If possible, please suggest me some good article to read about this, and the name of the concept if I am missing.

Comment: `struct msg_s = msg1 ;` should be `struct msg_s msg1;`

Comment: `data` is a non-modifiable r-value, or something like that. Either `unsigned char data[100];` should be `unsigned char * data;` or ... I don't know, you cannot assign a `malloc`'d address to it as it is now.

Comment: Google something about different int sizes (maybe even different floating point convention), struct member order, struct packing/padding and of course endianess. ->Serializing is not as simple as you think.

Answer (score 0):

I see many errors,

First,
 `Character array declaration inside struct mail doesn't following the C convention`

It should be like,

```
typedef struct mail{  
    char cc[30];   
    char bcc[30];  
    char body[30];  
}
```

2nd

Change `struct msg_s = msg1 ;` to `struct msg_s msg1 ;   // its a declaration of a struct msg1`

3rd

`unsigned char data[100];` is allocates 100 bytes memory in static memory.

and you are allocating the dynamic memory [heap] of size struct msg1 again by `data = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(msg1));` .

Change `unsigned char data[100];` to `unsigned char *data;`

In the client side,

```
struct msg_s *inMsg ;  
inMsg = malloc(sizeof(struct msg_s));  // malloc in c doesn't require typecasting
memcpy(inMsg ,data, sizeof(struct msg_s));
```